# Enabling the sharing of Flash content To Users' Facebook Timelines via my app

Tags: facebook

How do I submit a request for my app to be added to the whitelist of those via which expanded Flash Content posts can be shared/added to in-line user feeds?

I ask because having tried to find a way to contact Facebook directly via their site, I had no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature I think you are referring to is 'Feed Gaming' which is described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/feed-gaming/

The guide explains it all, but basically you're required to create an Open Graph object which provides the og:video meta tag, and which has an og:video:type of "application/x-shockwave-flash"

Hope that helps. No whitelist required.

Comment: Thanks a lot/ that's a great help so yeah, keep up the good work + enjoy the rest of your week. Regards, P.